# Laravel - class in namespace not found

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-8

I have this model class (the filename is Audit.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class AuditStatus
{
    const UNKNOWN = "UNKNOWN";
    const ERROR = "ERROR";
    const WARNING = "WARNING";
    const MSG = "MESSAGE";

    const EXCHANGE_UPDATE = "EXCHANGE_UPDATE";
    const PRICE_UPDATE = "PRICE_UPDATE";
}

class AuditCodes extends AuditStatus
{
}

class Audit extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['action', 'msg'];

    public static function Add($action, $msg){
        (new static)::insert(['action'=>$action, 'msg' => $msg]);
    }
}
```

And im trying to make a new command like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\AuditCodes;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PriceCreate extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'price:create';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create prices';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        dd(AuditCodes::MSG);
    }
}
```

but when I run the command the compiler throws this error:

```
 Error

  Class "App\Console\Commands\App\Models\Audit\Audit_Codes" not found

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\bintest\app\Console\Commands\PriceCreate.php:46
```

Can anyone help me on how to declare my class?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Adding a backslash and fixing the namespace, like `dd(\App\Models\Audit_Codes::MSG)` will fix that, or reference via the import `dd(Audit_Codes::MSG)`. Side note, model names are StudlyCase and singular, so `Audit_Codes` should be `AuditCode`.

Comment: If i add doublebackslash the error is  Class "App\Models\Audit\Audit_Codes" not found, if i use only one backslash the error is Class "App\Models\Audit\Audit_Codes" not found, and the error is the same using the "use" directive :(

Comment: Sorry, had to edit the comment a few times (re-read your question). It should be correct now  Single backslash, and you had an extra `\Audit`, which is not part of `namespace App\Models;`. Try it now

Comment: Nope... :( Class "App\Models\Audit\Audit_Codes" not found

Comment: Please re-read my comments; you have an extra `\Audit` in that. You have `namespace App\Models;`, not `namespace App\Models\Audit;`, so your `Audit_Codes` model is `\App\Models\Audit_Codes`, **and not `\App\Models\Audit\Audit_Codes`.**

Comment: nope, it doesnt work either, i changed it using camelCase rules (thanks for the tip) and tried dd(\App\Models\AuditCodes::MSG); and dd(\App\Models\Audit\AuditCodes::MSG);

Comment: thanks! just fixed my code to update all the changes you told me, the error is the same -> Class "App\Models\AuditCodes" not found

Comment: the class name is AuditCodes, I also changed it to singular (AuditCode) with the same error, maybe im not understanding it correctly can you add an answer with the correct use statements so i can try to spot the error? thanks!!!

Comment: One more thing to try, split your Classes into their own file each, instead of combining them in one file.

Comment: Thanks!! separating the classes did the trick.. :)

Comment: I began to wonder if that was the case after the repeated tries and errors. I'm a little surprised that it wouldn't work, I'll have to do some more digging to see what's up with that. Glad you got it working!

Comment: Yes, I was surprised too that it didnt worked, my goal was to group all the common code. I will have to do a little more digging too

Comment: Putting them in a subfolder is another option to separate them, like `app -> Models -> Auditing`, then `Audit.php`, `AuditCode.php` and `AuditStatus.php` (or however you want to name them), all with the correct namespace of `namespace App\Models\Auditing;`, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare each class in its own file.
I mean if you have three classes: Audit, AuditCodes and AuditStatus
You will also have three different files in `App\Models\` directory, like that `App\Models\Audit.php`, `App\Models\AuditCodes.php` and `App\Models\AuditStatus.php`.

It should be solve your problem.

Comment: This was already added as a suggestion via my latest comment. Please do not post this as an answer until the person asking the question has had an opportunity to attempt it as a solution, as if this is not correct, your answer will be downvoted and removed.

Comment: You lucked out in that this was the correct solution, but please try to follow the expected code of conduct on Stackoverflow. Posting someone else's comment as an answer is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Unless it is word by word copy of another answer, any answer shouldn't be taken as copied from others. Moreover, according to the existing code of conduct, if a member is new, the tone addressing the person should be a bit soft and welcoming. This has been discussed to death in meta.